# Run windows scheduler task only if a program is running

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I have created a task to kill a job which, now I want to put a condition to execute a scheduler action only if a program is running in tasklist for example -

Execute scheduler job only if chrome.exe is running

Comment: Do you mean you want to add this condition to the trigger for running the task, or do you mean you want this as the trigger (meaning run task whenever Chrome starts)?

Comment: I don't believe that trigger exists per se.  You could take the approach of running a periodic task (e.g. hourly.) and have it check whether Chrome is running and quit if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Run this .bat file with windows task scheduler as often as needed. In english the code says if program is running copy the folder, if the program is not running exit the batch file.
Look up the batch file code to replace `Robocopy "C:\123" "C:\123 Backup" /e` to do what you want it to when chrome.exe is running.

```
@echo off

tasklist | find /I "Chrome.exe" 
if errorlevel 1 (
        EXIT
) Else (
        Robocopy "C:\123" "C:\123 Backup" /e
)
```